# Ant jar file for simple java program

Tags: java, ant

I'm new to ant I build jar for simple example java program for Hello world .
jar is build but on click it is not opening what is problem.

Comment: On what do you click? What do you expect to happen when you click? What happens instead? What's your ant script to generate the jar file?

Comment: Actually im learning ant by download  example.Normally when we create jar file for swing on click jar it wil show gui right.i m not sure about for simple helloworld program

Comment: When you create a jar file, it creates a jar file. No GUI. When you execute a jar file, if the jar file happens to be a GUI application, its GUI will be dsplayed. If it isn't a GUI app, which GUI would you want it to display?

Comment: Thank You i did not get good tutorial for ant please suggest me some links if you know

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ant. With or without Ant, a non-GUI program doesn't display a GUI. The Ant reference manual is very good.

Comment: But i have doubt i will generate jar file directly in eclipse export option what is difference jar that has build by ant

Comment: Both generate a jar. What they put inside the jar depends on what you tell them to put inside. If you tell them to do the same thing, they'll do the same thing.

Comment: Just post the ant script you are using and it will be very easy to explain it to you

Comment: try running the jar file from console.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the generated jar file, you should make sure that the used class file is really included. Therefore I recommend to open the JAR file with an archive manager like WinZip, WinRAR or whatever you use and check if the helloWorld.class file is included in the JAR file.

Secondly, you have to specify which class is the Main-Class inside your JAR file:

```
<jar destfile="HelloWorld.jar">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="my.package.HelloWorld" />
    </manifest>
    ...
</jar>
```